# React Material UI Custom Input hide/show password

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to hide/show the password when a user clicks on the eye icon, but nothing changes.The default is the password is always visible, i want it to be always hidden.
[password text input][1]

My functions look like this

```
const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
const handleClickShowPassword = () => {setShowPassword({showPassword : showPassword}) };
const handleMouseDownPassword = () => {setShowPassword({showPassword : showPassword}) };
```

My text input code looks like this

```
                      <CustomInput
                        labelText="Password"
                        id="pass"
                        value={password}
                        type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                        formControlProps={{
                          fullWidth: true
                        }}
                        inputProps={{
                          onChange: (event) => {
                            const value = event.target.value;
                            setPassword(value)
                          },
                          endAdornment: (
                            <InputAdornment position="end">
                              <IconButton
                                aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                                onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                                onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                                >
                                  {showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
                              </IconButton>
                            </InputAdornment>
                          ),
                          autoComplete: "off"
                        }}
                      />
                      {
                            password === ""?
                            <p style={{color:"#D0021B"}}>{passworderror}</p>
                            :null
                          }
                          <p style={{color:"#D0021B"}}>{passwordexist}</p>
                          
                    </GridItem>  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/litjB.png
```

Comment: `const handleClickShowPassword = () => {setShowPassword({showPassword : showPassword}) };` doesn't quite look to be correct. Do you have a `showPassword` state and setter as well?

Comment: yes  `const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = React.useState(false);`

Comment: don't forget event.preventDefault() in handleClickShowPassword. To prevent the page from submitting and reloading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the useState Hook, then your handler should look like this:

```
const handleTogglePassword = () => setShowPassword(showPassword => !showPassword);
```

and the IconButton should look like this:

```
<IconButton
  aria-label="toggle password visibility"
  onClick={handleTogglePassword}
>
   {showPassword ? <Visibility /> : <VisibilityOff />}
</IconButton>
```

I think you mixed setState for class components and the useState for functional components.
Take a look here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate